# Count elements if over a certain value

Tags: python, list, count

I have a list of elements with certain values of type float. I want to iterate over the elements and count them if they are over a certain value, but also only count them if they appear over the treshold value a minimum_count of times. So for example, if a have following input:

```
list_of_values = [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0, 0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0, 0]
treshold_value = 1.0
minimum_count = 4
```

the answer should be 4, since the treshold_value 1.0 is consecutively exceeded 4 times only at indexes 0-3. I now have the code below,

```
for value in list_of_values:
    if value >= treshold_value:
        counter += 1
    if counter >= (minimum_count):
        time_use += 1
    if value < min_treshold_value:
        counter = 0
print(time_use)
```

I know there should be some pythonic way to achieve this :)

Edit: The sum of all consecutive subsequence values over the threshold should be counted.

Comment: what if the `list_of_values` has `1.0` as the 1st item? what should be the result?

Comment: Then the counter is incremented by 1, since 1.0 is >= treshold_value. All values < treshold_value should be ignored.

Comment: What if there is more than one run of numbers that satisfy the conditions, e.g. `[2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0, 0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 10.0, 0, 0]`? Should the result be 4, 5, or 9?

Comment: In this case the result should be 9.

Comment: So it's the index for the last appearance of the most represented value over `threshold`?

Comment: Or is it just the count of elements over `threshold`?

Comment: It is the count of the elements over the treshold, that appear in at least minimum_count consecutive times after each other.

Comment: @ConSod: So why should it be 9 in mhawke example?

Comment: @EricDuminil: Because 2.0 appears 4 times + 5 times and all consecutive values are over treshold_value

Comment: Could you please look at the example again? 2.0 doesn't seem to appear 5 times in a row

Comment: Sorry for my weak explanation @EricDuminil. It does not matter what value the numbers have, as long as there are at least minimum_count values next to eachother, that have values >= to treshold_value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to help:

```
from itertools import groupby

def count_runs(list_of_values, threshold_value=1.0, minimum_count=4):
    count = 0
    for k, g in groupby(list_of_values, key=lambda x: x >= threshold_value):
        if k:
            g = list(g)
            if len(g) >= minimum_count:
                count += len(g)
    return count

>>> count_runs([2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0, 0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0, 0])
0
>>> count_runs([2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0, 0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0, 0])
4
>>> count_runs([2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0, 0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 10.0, 0, 0])
9
```

This will provide the count of the number of values that are above the threshold in groups of `minimum_count` or more. Note that it handles multiple groups that match the criteria.

For example the `groupby()` for the last example will return the following:

```
>>> list_of_values = [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0, 0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 10.0, 0, 0]
>>> for k, g in groupby(list_of_values, key=lambda x: x >= threshold_value):
...     print(k, list(g))
... 
True [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0]
False [0, 0]
True [3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 10.0]
False [0, 0]
```

Any group of 1 or more values >= the threshold will appear in a group with key `True`. Only those with a length >= the minimum count will be considered further, where its length will be tallied with other such groups.

This code can be written more succinctly, and far less readably, like this:

```
def count_runs(list_of_values, threshold_value=1.0, minimum_count=4):
    return sum(count for count in (len(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(list_of_values, key=lambda x: x >= threshold_value) if k) if count >= minimum_count)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following use of [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with a conditional generator and [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) with appropriate key function should work:

```
from itertools import groupby

len(max((list(g) for k, g in groupby(list_ov, key=lambda x: x > threshold) if k), key=len))
```

`groupby` groups an iterable by consecutive identical values wrt to the key function. It produces pairs of the key value and according sub-iterable.

Comment: LOL, on a holiday hike with wife and mother... Bored to death, posting from the app on the phone :D must have checked the wiki box

Comment: Haha, enjoy your time with the missus.

Comment: This answer needs some explanation to be more helpful to those that do not already know `groupby()` etc.

Comment: How do I change this so that it sums all the subsequences over the treshold? I tried to remove the max(). Could you give a quick explanation of how this works? This is awesome, and I understand list comprehensions, but I do not understand how this works :)

Comment: @ConSod `sum(len(g) for k, g ...)` without the key argument of max (as there is no max call anymore)

Comment: @schwobaseggl thank you! I get following error: 'sum() takes no keyword arguments' , what am I doing wrong here? I have this version: ´len(sum((len(g) for k, g in groupby(list_of_values, key=lambda x: x > threshold) if k), key=len))´

Comment: @ConSod no more extra `len` call needed. The `key` param remains only for the groupby call.

Comment: `minimum_count` is not considered?

Answer (score 0):

just iterate over the list and create a dictionary with key = the float number and value = the number of times you encounter this number. and only add to dict floats that are greater then threshold . something like this:

```
d = {}
for f in   list_of_values :
    if f > treshold:
        if d.get(f,False):
             d[f] +=1
        else:
             d[f] = 1
max = 0
for k,v in d.iteritems():
    if v> max:
        max = v

return max
```

Comment: Well, you have a syntax issue with one of your for loops too.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't care about the order. In this case, `groupby` isn't correct because it only groups adjacent elements.

You could use a Counter and two list comprehensions to filter values:

```
list_of_values = [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0, 0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 10.0, 0, 0]
threshold_value = 1.0
minimum_count = 4

from collections import Counter
counter = Counter([x for x in list_of_values if x > threshold_value])
print(counter)
# Counter({2.0: 7, 3.0: 1, 10.0: 1})
print([(x, count) for x, count in counter.items() if count > minimum_count])
# [(2.0, 7)]
```